# How do you stream a binary representation of a .zip folder in mfc c++?

Tags: c++, mfc

I am trying to stream a .zip file to hardware using mfc c++. The hardware needs the file still in .zip format when sent over because it will do the unpacking itself.

I have been unable to find a class or method to grab a .zip file and stream it over.

Most searches lead me to questions about unzipping or zipping using c++ which is of no use in my particular case.

Any advice? Has anyone ran into this situation?

Comment: It seems you just need to read the file and give it to whatever API the hardware uses.

Comment: I don't quite understand the issue.  Just read the file and send the bytes of the file to the hardware.  I don't think it has anything to do with .zip or zipping and unzipping a file.

Comment: Why does the format of the file matter? Just treat it as a stream of bytes.

Comment: My issue is that I have used CFile in the past. And ot returns an error when trying to open the .zip. I'm asking if there is a known method for streaming this.

Comment: ***And ot returns an error when trying to open the .zip***  You need to examine the error and fix it. The OS should tell you some information about the error. There is nothing special about `.zip`. It's just a binary file that you need to push to your hardware device without altering its contents. Don't search for `.zip` that is not going to help you at all.

Comment: You used the term ".zip folder", perhaps your 'hardware' only handles a "zipped file".  Try sending a single compressed file to your hardware..

Comment: Make sure you are reading the file in binary mode. It certainly won't work in text mode.

Comment: Just open the file and read it byte per byte. Where is the problem? Opening and reading a file is very basic. _"And ot returns an error when trying to open the .zip"_: are you actually opening a zip file or are you trying to read a _folder_? Your question is very unclear, you need to give us more information. Please [edit] your question and clarify. Show at least the relevant parts of your failing code.

Answer (score 0):

The following code snippet reads the 100 first bytes of a file into a buffer using `CFile`:

```
CFile f;
if (f.Open(L"path_to_your_file", CFile::modeRead))
{
  char buffer[100];
  f.Read(buffer, sizeof buffer);
  f.Close();
}  
else
{
  // handle error

  DWORD error = GetLastError();
  // error number in error
  ...
}
```

This is more or less all you need. Google for the documentation of `CFile`.
You should be able to figure out the rest.

The format of the file you're reading is irrelevant. You just need to read the contents of your file and send it to the hardware.